# How can I remove the bar segment outlines from a bar chart?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this rather large data frame that I would like to create faceted bar plots from. It all works, but since the bar heights are stacked from many individual values, the bars are no longer a solid color, but dominated by the segment outline color.

The data frame looks like this:

```
> head(alldata[c("unit.size", "bppmbp")])
  unit.size     bppmbp
1         6 0.11927224
2        10 0.11430256
3         1 0.07951483
4         7 0.09442386
5        13 0.18884771
6         8 0.09939353
```

I want to plot the sum of bppmbp for each unit.size (unit.size goes from 1 to 51).

This is my code:

```
ggplot(data) + 
    aes(x=unit.size, y=bppmbp, fill=unit.size) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The result looks like this. The left screenshot is from the PDF output, the right one from the PNG output (a bit better, but you can still see the white borders).

[image: Bar plot with messed up bars (PDF)] [image: Bar plot with messed up bars (PNG)]

From [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/) I understand how to specify the outline color, but I have not found how to remove the outline entirely. I have tried adding `color=""`, `color=NA` or `color=element.empty()` to `geom_bar()`, but none of them do.

How can I remove that outline and have solid bars? Perhaps bin all the values and just plot the bin sums? I hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Try aggregating the data first, rather than relying on stacking in ggplot.

Comment: Thanks; you are probably right. I added a chunk of my data, but I guess the question should be "how can I aggregate this dataframe so ggplot does not make ugly stacks".

Comment: There are countless ways to aggregate data in R, and endless resources on the internet explaining how. Start looking into `aggregate` or packages like **plyr**, **dplyr** or **data.table**.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an example data frame like this:

```
    x   group subject
1  50    test       1
2  52    test       1
3  23    test       1
4  53    test       2
5  23    test       2
6  53    test       2
7  62 control       3
8  63 control       3
9  36 control       3
10 57 control       4
11 58 control       4
12 58 control       4

library(Rmisc);library(ggplot2)
dfc_subjects<- summarySE(df,measurevar = "x",groupvars = c("subject","group"))
dfc_subjects
  subject   group N    x         sd         se        ci
1       1    test 3 41.66667 16.1967075  9.3511734 40.234852
2       2    test 3 43.00000 17.3205081 10.0000000 43.026527
3       3 control 3 53.66667 15.3079500  8.8380491 38.027056
4       4 control 3 57.66667  0.5773503  0.3333333  1.434218
```

aggregated with individual subjects, and reduce that dimension in the plot.

```
ggplot(dfc_subjects, aes(x=group, y=x, color=group)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

You get this ugly looking thing. But if you do like this

```
dfc_group<- summarySE(df,measurevar = "x",groupvars = "group")
dfc_group
    group N        x       sd       se       ci
1 control 6 55.66667  9.93311 4.055175 10.42416
2    test 6 42.33333 15.01555 6.130072 15.75785

ggplot(dfc_group, aes(x=group, y=x, color=group)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

You get something that is aggregated over the group instead of individual cases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful! I guess the question should be less "how do I make ggplot less stacky" and more "how do I aggregate my data frame". `summarySE()` seems nice, but I would need a function that sums up a column depending on another. Basically, `aggregate()` or something. I added an example subset of my data.frame.

Comment: Accepted nonetheless. Thanks for the effort you put into showing me a way to aggregate my data!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is how I solved my problem using `aggregate()`:

```
> data.aggregate = aggregate(alldata$bppmbp, by = list(alldata$unit.size), sum)
> names(data.aggregate) = c("unit.size", "bppmbp")
```

This sums up the bppmbp column depending on the unit.size and gives me a much cleaner data frame that I can plot using the normal `ggplot(...) + geom_bar(...)`:

```
> head(data.aggregate)
  unit.size    bppmbp
1         1  87.30581
2         2  89.60076
3         3 701.26025
4         4  94.01366
5         5  49.36587
6         6 203.07879

> ggplot(tablata, aes(x=unit.size, y=bppmbp, fill=unit.size)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    xlab("Unit length") +
    ylab("bp/Mbp")
```

[image: Bar chart without stacking artifacts]